# Firefox stops to work after ugrade to version 19 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, firefox

Firefox starts and then it stops to work and I have to force close it. I tried to run it in safe mode and I reset it but nothing works.

Someone else has the same problem?

Thank you

Comment: Try renaming the .mozilla folder in home and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it's related to websnapshot extensions. I used to use picuzu shooter, when I take a snapshot firefox freezes and I have to delete the .mozilla directory. I also tried with other extensions:

- Awesome Screenshot Plus doesn't save the image using "save" button, if I right click and "Save image as" it freezes firefox.
- Pixlr Grabber doesn't save the picture but doesn't break firefox
- Screenshot by UploadScreenshot starts trying upload picture and it stops to work

**I found a solution** (or better a workaround). I can take the screenshot, when I save firefox hangs. I don't know the relation but the process gvfsd-metadata starts to use 100% of CPU.
I kill this process and all is back to normality. Not so confortable but it works!

Comment: [the same problem](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/reviews/446558/), Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

no problem here; Ubuntu 12.04 and FF 19

Try to remove firefox with Synaptic (or the softwarecenter) and choose complete removal. 
Then install Firefox again via the softwarecenter.

Make a back-up first of your bookmarks etc.